# Wildfly: Got permission denied when use RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, wildfly, permission-denied, randomaccessfile

When i try to open a RandomAccessFile for a named pipe located on host system i get the error below

```
12:54:45,048 SEVERE [com.dev.app.servlet.BackgroundListener] (Thread-514) null: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/centos/file (Permission denied)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
    at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:127)
    at deployment.app.war//com.dev.app.util.Reader.run(Reader.java:35)
```

The os permissions on the pipe are the following

```
prwxrwxrwx. 1 centos centos 0 Jun  2 12:50 file
```

And this is the code i'm using to access file

```
RandomAccessFile pipe = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
     pipe = new RandomAccessFile(Paths.PIPE, "rw");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(BackgroundListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

My server configuration: Wildfly 13, Jdk 10, Centos 7

On a debian machine the same war file it works correctly, what could be the cause of the issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: I also tried to chown to wildfly user with same result

Answer (score 1):

Got solution, it was a permission issue.
Altought permission was setted on 777 for /home/centos/file, the permission for the folder /home/centos was setted on 700

```
centos@ip ~ $ getfacl /home/centos
# file: home/centos
# owner: centos
# group: centos
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

Solved by fixing permission, thanks.